# The MAC Invalid

Tags: php, laravel

I just pushed up a fix on my Laravel system its using Encrypt and Decrypt out of the box nothing extra added, and came across this error

```
The MAC is invalid:
```

I have tried the following:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer update
```

I have also tried:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Has anyone else had the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
php artisan cache:clear 
composer clear-cache 
composer dump-autoload
```

and clear browser cache

Refer [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-mac-is-invalid-error-when-i-open-my-website?page=1)

Answer (score -1):

I have answered my own question, but for anyone else experiencing the same issue, you must delete all old data in the database that is encrypted..

Should have checked that first! NOOB